# sorting by two different values

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

if I have an array of structs that has two fields that I would like to sort by, how can I implement something like that? I already wrote a modified bubble sort algorithm that sorts an array.

They should be arranged in ascending order so the smaller values on the left. They will all be integer values, I just use some letter's to hopefully make it clearer.

let's say a struct

```
typedef struct {
    int top;
    int left;
    int right;
    int bottom;
}box;

box** boxes = calloc(1, sizeof(box) * 20);
```

let's say all those boxes has random values from -100, 100 in each for positions.

I can sort it by any one of the corners. Let's say we have boxes with top and left like this, i'll use letters for left but have it so that the array is arranged like this in the end.

```
start top, 0,1,2,3,4,5
start left a,b,c,d,e,f
```

after starting with something like this:

```
start top, 5,3,1,2,4,0
start left f,d,a,b,e,c
```

with the array being laid out like this:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,e,f
```

this is the sorting algorithm that I currently use:

```
static void obj_swap_func(box** a, box** b) {
    box* tp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tp;
}

void back_2_front(box** a, int count) {
    cg_sprite* l, *r;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int swap = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < (count - i - 1); j++) {
            if (a[j]->l_value > a[j + 1]->l_value) {
                obj_swap_func(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
                swap++;
            }
        }
        if (swap == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**trying to implement on of the answers below I wrote this function.**

```
static int greater(box* a, box* b) {
    if(a->top < b->top) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a->top > b->top) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a->left < b->left) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(a->left > b->left) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

then add it into the loop like this:
void back_2_front(box** a, int count) {
    cg_sprite* l, *r;

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int swap = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < (count - i - 1); j++) {
        if(greater(a[j], a[j+1])) {
            box_swap_func(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
            swap++;
        }
    }
    if (swap == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

}

the swap function looks like this:

```
static void box_swap_func(box** a, box** b) {
    box* tp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tp;
}
```

running this on a group of 50 boxes, this results in output like this:

```
box top:-48 box left: 3
box top:-47 box left: 3
box top:-46 box left: 3
box top:-45 box left: 3
box top:-44 box left: 3
box top:-43 box left: 3
box top:-42 box left: 3
box top:-41 box left: 2
box top:-40 box left: 2
box top:-39 box left: 2
box top:-38 box left: 2
box top:-37 box left: 2
box top:-36 box left: 2
box top:-35 box left: 2
box top:-34 box left: 1
box top:-33 box left: 1
box top:-32 box left: 1
box top:-31 box left: 1
box top:-30 box left: 1
box top:-29 box left: 1
box top:-28 box left: 1
box top:-27 box left: 4
box top:-26 box left: 4
box top:-25 box left: 4
box top:-24 box left: 4
box top:-23 box left: 4
box top:-22 box left: 4
box top:-21 box left: 4
box top:-20 box left: 3
box top:-19 box left: 3
box top:-18 box left: 3
box top:-17 box left: 3
box top:-16 box left: 3
box top:-15 box left: 3
box top:-14 box left: 3
box top:-13 box left: 2
box top:-12 box left: 2
box top:-11 box left: 2
box top:-10 box left: 2
box top:-9 box left: 2
box top:-8 box left: 2
box top:-7 box left: 2
box top:-6 box left: 1
box top:-5 box left: 1
box top:-4 box left: 1
box top:-3 box left: 1
box top:-2 box left: 1
box top:-1 box left: 1
box top:0 box left: 1
box top:2 box left: 4
```

it sorts by the top just fine but as you can see they are being sorted correctly by the top value but not by the left value.

Did I write the algorithm correctly?

Comment: you need to say what the rule is (in code) for box1 being > box2

Comment: Take another look at the output: the boxes are in ascending order, with more significance given to y- than to x-coordinate. That you don't _see_ order in _left_ is due to lack of boxes that _share the same top_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key modification you have to make is replace the line

```
if (a[j]->l_value > a[j + 1]->l_value) {
```

by

```
if ( is_greater(a[j], a[j+1]) ) {
```

where

```
int is_greater(box a1, box a2)
{
   // Make the logic as simple or as complex as needed.
}
```

The simplest implementation, which is equivalent to what you have, is:

```
int is_greater(object* a1, object* a2)
{
   return (a1->l_value > a2->l_value);
}
```

It's not clear from your post how `box` and `object` are related. I can't suggest any further improvements without that information.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Your implementation of `is_greater` is buggy.

If your sorting algorithm can use the return values of:

less than zero
 zero
 greater than zero

instead of

-1
 0
 1

You can use:

```
static int greater(box* a, box* b) {

    if(a->top != b->top) {
       return (a->top - b->top);
    }

    return (a->left - b->left);
}
```

If your sorting algorithm expects -1, 0, and 1, you can use:

```
static int greater(box* a, box* b) {

    if(a->top != b->top) {
       if(a->top < b->top) {
          return -1;
       else
          return 1;
    }

    if (a->left < b->left) {
       return -1;
    }
    else if (a->left > b->left) {
       return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems to sort only by on element instead of two. I updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like `back_2_front` function sorts an array of `object` structs, where each instance has a `l_value` field.

The easiest way for you to make the necessary changes to sort `box` instances instead of `object` instances would be to define a function that does the comparison for you:

```
int compareBoxes(box * a, box* b)
{
    if(a==NULL or b==NULL) return 0; //do your preferred method of error handling

    //check by top first
    if(a->top < b->top) 
    {
        return 0; //returns false if first object has smaller top
    }
    else if (a->top > b->top)
    {
        return 1; //returns true if first object has greater top
    } 

    //at this point the tops are equal, feel free to compare by other fields...

}
```

and then inside your inner for loop instead of  `a[j]->l_value > a[j + 1]->l_value`  you can have `compareBoxes(a[j], a[j+1])`

Remember that you will need to write a swap function for boxes instead of objects.

Comment: I tried implementing this but all I am getting is the objects being sorted by the first element and the second element isn't sorted. I'll update the question with what I wrote.

Comment: you are right, the answer was right there. Thank you.